# How to change Default Recording device using LabVIEW?

Tags: labview

We have a LabVIEW application that is based on sound acquisition.

I connected a Custom USB Audio device (Microphone). It is set to be the default Recording device.

But while running the application, if there is another mic source connected, then sound is being recorded/acquired by the other mic and not the default one.

So in order to have the custom microphone do the acquisition, I tried to change the default Audio Recording device through LabVIEW. But all I can do is list the audio devices connected by running a PowerShell command through System Exec function.

Is there any possible way to change the default recording device using LabVIEW? Please do mention if any.

Comment: Can you show us the LabVIEW code that does the sound acquisition (preferably as a [VI Snippet](http://www.ni.com/tutorial/9330/en/))? Does it use [Sound Input Configure](https://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361P-01/lvpict/sinput_config/) and if so what's wired to `Device ID`?

Answer (score 1):

Back in the day, I had a similar requirement, I did the following!

1. Get All microphones connected on the PC.
   [image: Get List of Microphones]
2. Once I get all the Device IDs, I performed a search using "Device Name" to get the Device ID I needed!

Note: If the above VI returns only one microphone, then make sure you've installed DirectX on the PC.

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Hi @BalaGopi, Was this useful for you?

Comment: It works perfectly for me! Thank you! @Achuthaperumal RK: it would be useful to show "Parameters" tabs in both nodes... Note that may help: you can see parameters in the "Function prototype" below.

Answer (score 0):

Hello am very late for this information, but I can provide you with a few things you need to do.

1. Tap setting
2. Choose my device
3. Difficult device
4. Select and activate

Or

Visit Cpanel select program and tap on device activety, now choose difficult setting.

Answer (score -1):

To change difficult device follow each of the steps above:
1.Setting
2.Device
3. Select difficult program
May any changes you want then done.

Comment: I already tried it and I made sure that the custom mic is set as Default. Still the application picks other mic if available. Thanks.